# Adding subfolder path in deployed application

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I am trying to deploy a simple console application using MATLAB Compiler.

However, we can't use `addpath()` in deploying applications.

I would like to know, how can we add a subfolder containing functions and data files and later how to use them.

Possible answer to access a file would be:

```
fp = fopen(fullfile(ctfroot, 'my', 'data', 'directory', 'data.file'));
```

However, this doesn't explain how to add path to access those functions in a subdirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `addpath` is not supported in the `deploytool`, you should add the files in your `source files` while you are trying to build an executable. If for some reason you don't want to add the entire data (maybe too big?), you can then provide only the data path as input. Then read the data files from that path. If you do this, be careful when you distribute the application.

Comment: yes, that worked, I just had to use isdeployed function while in matlab and add folder to deployment project to build.